# Updating a root css style through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I need to set theme color which is passed as a model attribute from my controller to my CSS file using JavaScript.

Here is the current CSS file root part:

```
:root {
    --clr-primary: #ffca00;
    --clr-dark-blue: #1d1836;
    /* --clr-accent: #4917D6; */
    --clr-black-900: #1f1f1f;
    --clr-black-800: #303030;
    --clr-black-600: #3f3f3f;
    --clr-white-off: #f7f7f7;
}
```

I need to update '--clr-primary' to whatever theme color when the page loads.

So what I did was using JavaScript:

```
    var jsonThemeColor = $('#menuThemeColor').val();
    var themeColor = JSON.parse(jsonThemeColor)
    console.log(themeColor)
    root.style.setProperty('--clr-primary',jsonThemeColor);
```

Yet this doesn't work. Mind you, I have a separate CSS file I have not included CSS inside a `<style>` tags. So there are no errors, it's just that the color is not getting updated and instead it's showing white color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--property', 'color');
```

You can visit this [link](https://codepen.io/wesbos/pen/adQjoY) for a demo created by wesbos.